# How can I install Nvidia Gstreamer plugins (nvenc, nvdec) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, plugins, gstreamer

I do like to accelerate `GStreamer` by making use of my GPU card, I have seen this [tutorial](https://lifestyletransfer.com/how-to-install-nvidia-gstreamer-plugins-nvenc-nvdec-on-ubuntu), but it seems to be outdated!

**Nvidia Video Codec SDK** doesn't have `include` folder to copy anymore, moreover I have `libdrm2` and not `libdrm`.

After installation (according to the tutorial), I inspect the encoder:
`gst-inspect-1.0 nvdec`

> No such element or plugin 'nvdec'

##### Is there any way to install Nvidia Gstreamer plugins (nvenc, nvdec) on Ubuntu 20.04 properly?

Comment: The article that you linked to was written in March of 2020, so it's hardly "old". Did you follow the instructions to install the plugins? Did you receive any error messages? If so, which ones? Help us help you by providing some specifics 

Comment: Is Your use case just watching videos with `hardware video decoding`? You can install `mpv` and start from there, it should properly detect if Your gpu has such capability and use it. In the OSD press `i` to see more info during playback.

Comment: @matigo I have edited the question to clarify the issue, thanks for your notes.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz I use `hardware video decoding` to accelerate my frame rate for faster image processing, features extraction.